# .net core 2.2. Circular References

Tags: reference, .net-core, circular-reference

I have problem with references and  got confused.

In DLL `Repository.Implement` i can see DLL`Model` and use the model in repository layer.

When i want to add references between DLL `Infrastructure` and DLL`Model`say me its circular references.

In this [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvzJw.jpg) can see my solution infrastructure

What Should i do to resolve indirect references ?

Answer (score 0):

What does `Repository.Model` depend on?  If you get a circular reference when both `Repository.Implement` and `Repository.Infrastructure` reference Repository.Model then Model must depend on (or depend on something that depends on) `Model` or `Infrastructure`.

To solve the problem you will have to identify which project is causing the loop and break it. This may mean restructuring your code.